# How to use joi validator with strapi.js?

Tags: joi, strapi

I have worked a lot with `joi` with node's express and little with `Hapi.js`. And now I'm exploring the `Strapi.js`. Now I have marked that when I create a `Content Type builder` it gives me basic CRUD API's. Now I want to validate all request using `joi`. As `strapi` makes all routes in JSON file. So how could I use joi? I had search a lot but I'm not getting any solution on this.

I have found one solution like this.

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "path": "/users",
  "handler": "users.create",
  "validate":{               <---------------- Hear I  can validate my req
      body:{
          fname: Joi.string().required()
      }
  },            
  "config": {
    "policies": []
  }
}
```

Hear the issue is they used `Joi` but I have to define its package name but hear I have a JSON file so I'm not able to do like this.

Is there anyone has a solution to this?

**Update**

I have renamed the file as a `router.json`.

```
const router = require('koa-joi-router');
const Joi = router.Joi;
module.exports = {
   "routes": [
      {
           "method": "POST",
           "path": "/tests",
           "validate":{
              "body":{
                 "name":Joi.string().required()
               }
            },
            "handler": "Test.create",
             "config": {
                "policies": []
              }
        },
   ]
}
```

Still `Joi` is not working.

Answer (score 4):

OKay after having investigated on this topic, you will not be able to manage your validation in this way.

I suggest you to manage your validation layer with a middleware.

1. Use your route file with a JSON format (like the default one)
   then in the `config` object you add the validation key that contains your validation schema. But you validation skema will be a string.

Here is an example:

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "path": "/articles",
  "handler": "Article.create",
  "config": {
    "policies": [],
    "validate":{
      "body":{
         "name": "string.required"
       }
    }
  }
},
```

2. Then you will have to follow the [Middleware documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/advanced/middlewares.html#custom-middlewares)  to create you validation middelware.

In this middleware you will be able to get the requested url with `ctx.request.url` and with a `.find()` in `strapi.config.routes` you will be able to find your validation configs.

Then you will have to use the JSON validation config you set and recompose the Joi validation on your request body - `ctx.request.body`

Comment: Thanks for another reply. I'll try to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

For the `routes.json` file, you can rename it `routes.js` and add a **module.exports** and your json file become an js file.

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      ...
```

-

```
module.exports = {
  "routes": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
```

But it's only a part of the response.

Comment: Okay let me try this way.

Comment: As you told, I have set `js` instead of `json`. Now I can use `joi`. But now issue is joi is not working. I have set `name` as a required and when I call API from postman, It's not getting an error from joi. Can you please tell me why it's not working?